# nn.Conv2d causing error in multi-GPU learning

Tags: parallel-processing, pytorch, conv-neural-network, gpu, training-data

I posted a similar question recently, but I think I overcomplicated the question as I hadn't narrowed down the issue quite yet. Here is the context:

I am currently creating a custom module inside an existing CNN using pytorch. I am doing this as part of my schools research, and so I have access to a super computer with multiple GPU devices. When I train my model, after running through the first validation set I run into the following error:

> RuntimeError: Expected all tensors to be on the same device, but found at least two devices, cuda:1 and cuda:0! (when checking argument for argument weight in method wrapper__cudnn_convolution)

Now, this does not happen when I skip the convolution in my module and just put some dummy calculation in. This error also doesn't raise when I use a single gpu or a cpu. Here is my custom module. The convolution takes place in the 'conv_gauss' function at the very bottom:

```py
class DivisiveNormBlock(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self, channel_num = 512, size = 56, ksize = 4):
        super().__init__()
        self.channel_num = channel_num
        self.size = size
        self.ksize = ksize

        scale = 90  # Random scale factor I've been playing with.
        self.theta = torch.nn.Parameter(scale * torch.abs(torch.randn(self.channel_num, self.channel_num, device="cuda",
                                                                      requires_grad=True)))  # 512 thetas for a channel, 512 channels, same goes for...
        self.p = torch.nn.Parameter(
            scale * torch.abs(torch.randn(self.channel_num, self.channel_num, device="cuda", requires_grad=True)))
        self.sig = torch.nn.Parameter(
            scale * torch.abs(torch.randn(self.channel_num, self.channel_num, device="cuda", requires_grad=True)))
        self.a = torch.nn.Parameter(
            scale * torch.abs(torch.randn(self.channel_num, self.channel_num, device="cuda", requires_grad=True)))
        self.nI = torch.nn.Parameter(
            torch.abs(torch.randn(self.channel_num, self.channel_num, device="cuda", requires_grad=True)))
        self.nU = torch.nn.Parameter(torch.abs(torch.randn(self.channel_num, device="cuda", requires_grad=True)))
        self.bias = torch.nn.Parameter(torch.abs(torch.randn(self.channel_num, device="cuda", requires_grad=True)))
        self.gaussian_bank = torch.zeros(self.channel_num, self.channel_num, self.ksize * 2+ 1, self.ksize * 2+ 1,
                                         device="cuda")
        self.x = torch.linspace(-self.ksize, self.ksize, self.ksize * 2 + 1, device="cuda")
        self.y = torch.linspace(-self.ksize, self.ksize, self.ksize * 2 + 1, device="cuda")
        self.xv, self.yv = torch.meshgrid(self.x, self.y)

        for i in range(self.channel_num):
            for u in range(self.channel_num):
                self.gaussian_bank[i, u, :, :] = self.get_gaussian(i, u)

        p = int((self.ksize * 2) / 2)
        conv_kernel_size = self.ksize * 2+ 1
        self.conv = nn.Conv2d(self.channel_num, self.channel_num, padding=p, stride=1,
                              kernel_size=conv_kernel_size, bias=False)


    def get_gaussian(self, cc, oc):  #
        xrot = self.xv * torch.cos(self.theta[cc, oc]) + self.yv * torch.sin(self.theta[cc, oc])
        yrot = -self.xv * torch.sin(self.theta[cc, oc]) + self.yv * torch.cos(self.theta[cc, oc])
        g_kernel = (self.a[cc, oc] / \
                    (2 * torch.pi * self.p[cc, oc] * self.sig[cc, oc])) * \
                   torch.exp(-0.5 * ((((xrot) ** 2) / self.p[cc, oc] ** 2) + ((yrot) ** 2) / self.sig[cc, oc] ** 2))

        return g_kernel

    def forward(self, x):

        x_test = self.dn_f(x)

        return x

    def dn_f(self, x):


        batch_size = x.shape[0]
        under_sum = torch.zeros((self.channel_num, self.size, self.size), device="cuda")
        normalized_channels = torch.zeros((batch_size, self.channel_num, self.size, self.size), device="cuda")
        for b in tqdm(range(batch_size)):
            for i in range(self.channel_num):
                for u in range(self.channel_num):
                    under_sum[u] = self.conv_gauss(torch.pow(x[b, i], self.nI[i, u]), self.gaussian_bank[i, u])
                    #under_sum[u] = under_sum[u]
                normalized_channels[b, i] = torch.pow(x[b, i], self.nU[i]) / (
                        torch.pow(self.bias[i], self.nU[i]) + torch.sum(under_sum, 0))
        return normalized_channels

    def conv_gauss(self, x_conv, gauss_conv):

        x_conv = torch.reshape(x_conv, (1, 1, self.size, self.size))
        gauss_conv = torch.reshape(gauss_conv, (1, 1, self.ksize * 2+ 1, self.ksize * 2+ 1))
        p = int((self.ksize*2)/2)
        self.conv.weight = nn.Parameter(gauss_conv)
        output = self.conv(x_conv)
        output = torch.reshape(output, (self.size, self.size))
        return output
```

For some extra context, I also did tried this with `F.conv2d` in the function instead, but to no avail.

Comment: This is a **lot** of code to take in, and you have not shown how to reproduce the issue. How do you use this code? What do you change between the single-GPU and multi-GPU cases? Please try to create a **minimal**, **reproducible** example.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).